# Functional JS cookies - disclaimer?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using JS cookies to check if an image is already loaded and to skip the loading animation in case it is. This is the only thing I need cookies for. Do I need a cookie disclaimer according to german law? Those cookies are just a convenient way to skip the animation. Without them everything would work fine but you get a misplaced animation.

I've read a lot of articles about it but I am still not quite sure as most sites say functional cookies are only cookies which are really necessary for the site to work.

Comment: If that's a business website, then you need a disclaimer. It's annoying, I know, but it's the law - you have to notify for ANY cookie usage. There are templates for this. However, if it's a personal website, then you can do without the disclaimer.

Comment: @vlaz That is incorrect, you don't need to notify about "functional" cookies (session token cookie for example).

Comment: @FINDarkside are my cookies considered "functional cookies"?

Comment: No idea, and tbh this is probably the wrong place to ask this kind of question anyway. If you gave more specifics about what you're trying to do, we could try to offer alternative without cookies at all.

Comment: From a technical standpoint, the implementations of the [Storage web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) can often replace most cookie usages (expect stuff like server-side session tracking).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i know about localStorage but AFAIK the cookie law also affects it.

Comment: @FINDarkside its pretty simple. Show a loading animation until image gets into viewport, if image is in the viewport load it and replace it with the loading indicator. Safe it in the cookies that I know it is already cached. If an image is already cached skip animation and viewport checking.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're doing and I'm not sure why you're using cookies for it. Why do you need to check if the image is cached? If it's cached it'll load so quickly that it doesn't matter if you "show" the loading indicator. Are you caching them manually or are you talking about browser caching them?

Comment: @FINDarkside The problem comes with the viewport check. I want to start downloading the image when its in the viewport. While its downloading the loading indicator is shown. Without cookies i wouldnt know if the image is already cached so it waits until its in the viewport shows the loading indicator for a millisecond and then gets replaced by the actual image which is already cached but the script doesnt know. I only want the loading animation when i know the image is not yet cached.

Comment: By "cached" you mean it's literally part of the viewport? As that's not what most people would assume by cache. Cookies sound really wrong tool for the job, you're supposed to use cookies for stuff that needs to be sent to the server every requst. Simply store a object holding state of the images. imagesLoaded[imageUrl] = true; when you load one. I think you should make a new question with code samples, as you absolutely should not be using cookies for this.